# Convert string to BigDecimal and add Comma Delimiter

Tags: java, format, bigdecimal

I've got a string that i'm reading from a file. This string should be converted to BigDecimal. Once it's in bigdecimal i've got something like this: `000000000103000000`. All the 0's before the first number shall be formatted away and the last two `00` should be `.00` how would i accomplish this? eg. `(000000004711) -> (47.11)`

Code:

```
BigDecimal amount;
String line = "30000000000000010300000000000000000000009876543210";
final NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);/* , instead of . */

while((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {

    amount = BigDecimal.valueOf(formatter.parse( 
    line.substring(2,24).replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "")).longValue());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to remove the first zeros, it will be ignored when you convert it to BigDecimal, you just need to put the dot before the two last digits :

```
String line = "30000000000000010300000000000000000000009876543210";
if (line.length() >= 22) {
    BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(
            line.substring(2, 24).replaceFirst("^(.*)(..)$", "$1.$2")
    );
    System.out.println(amount);
}
```

**Output**

```
30000000000000010300000000000000000000009876543210 -> 1030000.00
```

Comment: You accidentally removed `.substring(2,24)` edit it and i'll approve. Thanks

Comment: Oops, you want just a specific part then? ok I will edit it

Comment: correct, I have to parse out 2,24 as that is where the numbers are supposed to reflect the amount, the rest of the string is other information :) 0's act as fillers.

Comment: @Joel you have to add `line = line.length() > 1 ? line : "0" + line;` before you convert the string to BigDecimal else you will get wrong result with a number with one digit

Comment: yeah i was thinking about that actually. However, then i could just use my regex but like this? `"^0+(?!$)", "$1.$2"` ?

Comment: @Joel your regex is not useful, it will throw an exception `No group 1` did you test it?

Comment: oh yeah, that's true. mb, not very good with regex. I still don't like that i have to use the line condition here with this solution, as it sort of messes with the rest of my parsing.

Comment: `if((line = line.length() > 1 ? line : "0" + line) != "") {` would do the trick right?

Comment: @Joel no string should be compared by `.equals` or `isEmpty()` in your case, beside if your number should be equal or more than 22 digits, then you can use `line = line.substring(2, 24);
        if (line.length() >= 22) {
            BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(line.replaceFirst("^(.*)(..)$", "$1.$2"));
        }`

Comment: @Joel can you share the range of the digit so I can give you a better solution?

Comment: the range is 2,24 or what do you mean? the number can be anywhere within that range. I'm just supposed to trim until a number other than 0 appears. then add the decimal thing :)

Comment: ok @Joel then I would like to use my edit now, check again, this is the better way to go, I test the length before I use `substring`

Comment: Could you try to explain what this does different than your previous solution? It works but I don't know why.

Comment: @Joel the idea is just to check the length before you make `substring` because if the length of the line is less than `22` character `(24-2)` it will throw an exception.

Comment: Okay, but `if(!(line = line.length() > 1 ? line : "0" + line).isEmpty()) {` should also work right? :) Thanks for your patience

Comment: @Joel It will fail if the length is less than 22 character, because you are using `.substring(2, 24)` just try with another string for example `000456` and you will see that it will throw `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 24`, beside no problem you can ask any thing don't worry ;)